# App Installation "blocked by your IT admin"? (Galaxy Note 8)

Tags: applications, security, youtube, device-administrator, unknown-sources

I use YMusic to listen to music/audio books, which is an outsider app from xda-developers. When I tried to install an update, I got the message below, as if YouTube is preventing me from installing the app. Here's a Screenshot:

[image]

I wanna mention a couple of things:

- This is my personal device, so there's no IT admin
- developer mode is enabled on the device
- It's not the first time I install apps from unknown sources. Usually I have to authorize them during the installation, and this source is authorized
- It's not a rooted device
- it's the latest available version of Android, security update May, 1st 2019

EDIT: After a couple of days, that message didn't appear anymore. Maybe the app had something that conflicts with YouTube, and it was updated? I don't know.

Comment: Check the Android security settings for "device admin apps". These apps can restrict certain functions on your device, therefore this interface is at the moment used by IT admins to manage devices. Therefore I assume the massage assumes you have a managed device.

Comment: @Robert The only app enabled there is a "Find My Device" app... nothing with YouTube.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Device admin apps can block certain actions (like installing app xyz) on your device. But if you only have "Find My Device" active this can't be the source of the restriction.

Comment: While this is your personal device, did you log in with any managed account (e.g. work account)? Is "Device Policy" app installed?

Comment: @AndrewT. Nope. Absolutely unrelated to anything at work. Actually at work we cannot do that due to security procedures.